# Open a local docker container terminal from VsCode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am having trouble executing a terminal in VSCode to link with bash from a docker container. Currently, I am using "docker exec -it /bin/bash" to access what I need, but I am wondering if it is possible to create a new terminal directly in the container.

Thank you for your help!